NestJs (Typescript mode), error with Axios and GET request
I am currently developing a microservice with NestJs in typescript which calls an API, when I test my GET route (of the microservice) with Postman, i obtain the desired results with a JSON object of my data but when I call the microservice routes from another web application in Ajax I get this error:

here is the function that performs the GET request (app.service.ts) :
async offersById(idEligibility: string) {
    const requestConfig = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: this.configService.get('TOKEN_ALPHALINK'),
        Connection: 'keep-alive',
      },
    };

    const response = await lastValueFrom(
      this.httpService
        .get(
          `${this.configService.get('URL_ALPHALINK')}retailer/eligibility/get_offer/?id=${idEligibility}`,
          requestConfig,
        )
        .pipe(
          catchError((error) => {
            Logger.error(
              `Error occurred while fetching offers: ${JSON.stringify(error)}`,
            );
            return throwError(
              new HttpException(
                'Error occurred while fetching offers',
                HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
    );

    if (response.data.length === 0) {
      throw new HttpException(
        "Aucune offre éligible n'a été trouvée",
        HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
      );
    }

    const result = response.data.response ? response.data : null;

    if (result) {
      const fttoModel = new FttoModel(
        result.ideligibility,
        result.info,
        result.address,
        this.FTTOX,
      );

      Object.keys(result.data).forEach((key) => {
        const category = result.data[key];
        Object.keys(category.list).forEach((subKey) => {
          const technology = category.list[subKey];
          Object.keys(technology.list).forEach((subKey2) => {
            const packaging = technology.list[subKey2];
            Object.keys(packaging.list).forEach((offerKey) => {
              this.getResults(packaging.list[offerKey], fttoModel);
            });
          });
        });
      });

      return fttoModel;
    }
  }

and here is the route called in my app.controller.ts :
@Get('/eligibility/offer/:ideligibility')
  async getOffersById(@Param() params: any) {
    if (!params || !params?.ideligibility) {
      throw new HttpException(
        `Identifiant d'éligibilité invalide`,
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
    return this.appService.offersById(params.ideligibility);
  }

And here is the Ajax call :
$.ajax({
     url: "http://localhost:3000/eligibility/offer/" + JSON.parse(html.responseText).ideligibility,
     type: "GET",
     contentType: "application/json",
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
     data: {},
     complete: (function (html) {
         //logic...
     })
});

Thank you guys a lot, i'm struggling hard with that one.
Maybe something about XSRF token ?
